# Problema para pasar un arreglo php a javascript con laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, array, laravel-5

Estoy intentando pasar un `array` de direcciones que viene de mi `controller` a un arreglo de `javasript`. Mi arreglo de direcciones es el siguiente:

```
public function Direcciones_hermano(){

        return Direcciones::where('tipo', 0)->where('persona_id', $this->id)->get();
    }
```

cada elemento dirección contiene lo siguiente:

```
public $fillable = [
        'persona_id',
        'calle',
        'numero',
        'apto',
        'entre_prim',
        'entre_seg',
        'municipio_id',
        'reparto',
        'tiempo_residencia',
        'anterior',
        'tipo'
    ];
```

Lo que intento es pasar ese `array` que estoy trayendo de mi `controller` a un 
 `array` que esta en una plantilla `Blade`. Hasta este punto estoy haciendo un json en mi plantilla blade que es el siguiente:

```
@json( $regMiembro->persona->Direcciones_hermano() )
```

pero no se como asignar los valores al array que tengo javascript.

Alguna idea me pudieran brindar

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let data  = @json( $regMiembro->persona->Direcciones_hermano());
    console.log(data);
</script>
```